# QMediaPlayer is not showing the video

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on video player and now i'm doing my playlists functional. So, when i've made a little system, but it's not working. Can you please say what's wrong with it? He enables audio but don't show the picture when i add the second video.

```
void videoWindow::video_enable(QVideoWidget *output, const QString &path)
{
    int i = 1;
    player = new QMediaPlayer;

    playlist = new QMediaPlaylist;
    qDebug() << path;
    qDebug() << *filename;

    playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path)); // test of the user's path

    if (i == 1)
    {
        player->setPlaylist(playlist);
        playlist->setCurrentIndex(1); // start from a first video in the playlist
    }
    else
    {
        playlist->next();
    }

    player->setVideoOutput(output);
    player->play();
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You `i` will never get other value than 1 (so `else` path will never be performed) - because it is automatic variable set to ` on every execution of videoWindow::video_enable. Maybe you forgot to make it `static`?

Comment: @mvidelgauz i fixed it, but there is the same problem: i can play two or more videos in one moment, plus i don't have a picture, excepting the first video.

Comment: Let's clarify, it does play but picture is not rendered? Maybe you don't have needed codec installed? Try to play the same file with player outside of your program

Comment: And btw your 'playlist` is also recreated every time (same as `i`) so it never will be advanced more than once

Comment: @mvidelgauz I've fixed the i problem and checked the variable with qDebug(), but this problem stays all the time. And i can open the first video, but then i don't have a picture. If i don't play the first video, it's not working, if i play, it works only with the first video.

Comment: post your corrected code please

Comment: @mvidelgauz Sorry, already fixed it. Moderator, you can close the topic.